# Plaster identification and screw recommendation

Tags: plumbing, drywall, screws, plaster, drywall-anchor

I need to fasten standard 15mm water pipes to a division wall in my house (built in UK in the 1970's). Some clips are already in place, but I need to add more (I am talking about clips like this: https://www.wolseley.co.uk/product/center-hinged-wrap-over-pipe-clip-15-mm/).

I am only familiar with brick, cement-plastered walls, so please bear with my newbieness:

1. What kind of wall and plastering do I have? See the pics of a hole in a wall on the same floor:

https://postimg.cc/gallery/2c7gbb97m/

2. What kind of screws (material, size, shape, gauge) do you recommend?
3. Should I use plugs (anchors)? I unmounted one of the existing clips and the screw seems to have none.

Any further advice on what I should/shouldn't do, or anything else, is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a standard drywall wall. I have used these anchors for years with much success. They can be installed without drilling and removed easily without a lot of damage to the wall and used again. I've included a picture of them. They can be used with #6 or #8 screws.[image]